# Import CSV error

Tags: r, csv

I get the following error msg when importing any CSV file after updating R

> O Preparing data import  Required package versions could not be found:
>   readxl 0.1.0 is not available  Check that getOption(" repos") refers
>   to a CRAN repository that contains the  needed package versions.

regardless of what file I am trying to import. New to R unsure how I am screwing up.

Comment: `readxl` is a package to read excel files. Are you sure you are reading a CSV file?

Comment: And what is your code?

Comment: Please mention your code as well.

Comment: Did you install the `readxl` package?

Comment: wasnt even trying to use code. was using the import dataset in the environment window which triggered the error. Very familiar with excel and I know the file is a csv

Comment: also  Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘readxl’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)